# VIM Hotkey Creation

Tags: linux, vim, terminal, python, hotkeys

I'm pretty new to VIM and linux in general.  So doing this on my own is well beyond my skill level now.  I'm familiar with vimrc file but that is it...

Let's say I have one terminal open idling.  Then I open another terminal, and edit a python (.py) file with vim.  How can I create a permanent hotkey (like f1, for example), that will work on all VIM modes, that will save the python file and execute it in the other terminal window?

Comment: le google: http://alisnic.github.io/posts/vim-run-hotkey/ -- oh and running something in another terminal is not trivial, unless you want to start a new terminal. I'd say just forget about it for now... Perhaps someone will have a better suggestion :) welcome to SU!

Answer (score 1):

Executing a command in another existing terminal can be done, but it is far from trivial.

First, you have more than one terminal emulator open. Those terminal emulators are running a shell, probably `bash` if you're on Linux. With the `ps` command you can find the process ids (PID) of all the shells running on your machine. The big question now is; which one to send the command to?

You are looking for a shell that belongs to the terminal wou want to show the command on. Running the command `echo $$` on the terminal in question should return the PID of the shell running on that terminal.
Using the `/proc` filesystem you can determine the shell's standard input `/proc/<PID>/fd/0`, which is a `pty` device.

Next you want to send a command to that terminal. This has to be done using the `TIOCSTI`  `ioctl` command on the shell's pty. You can find the C source code to do that [here](http://www.humbug.in/2010/utility-to-send-commands-or-data-to-other-terminals-ttypts/). Compile that program as e.g. `ttyecho` and put it in a directory in your $PATH.

Now the pieces are in place, and you could call the `ttyecho` command with the name of the shell's pty, and the command `python <filename>`.

Doing all this in vimscript is left as an exercise for the reader. :-)

Answer (score -1):

You can try something like this (same terminal):

```
map <F2>:w<CR>!C:\Python27\python.exe %<CR><CR>
```

Comment: appleLover mentioned he is on Linux

Comment: That's hardly a reason to vote the answer down. The Vim command is identical in a unix environment apart from the binary path. I'm all for pedantry, but you sir take the cake :)

Comment: I do not see the point of giving an answer that will *definitely not work* for the person asking, unless he does proper modifications. That might be good for educational purposes but well... we are not in a classroom.